# Sharepoint Provider Hosted app with Odata Web API

Tags: sharepoint, asp.net-web-api2, odata, sharepoint-2013

We have a requirement to build a SharePoint Provider hosted app, which needs to call to a ASP.NET Web API built with Odata. I could't find a exact solution for this. Any help to perform this would be highly approciated

Answer (score 0):

It should be like any other web application as the provider hosted App is totally independent from SharePoint.

IF you are building the app using asp.net, then you can just add a reference to the odata endpoint, ex: http://yourservice/odata/$metadata

Visual Studio will generate a proxy to all entities in the odata service.

If you are building the app using other technology, then deal with the service as a normal REST service and call it using any HTTP client, from browser or a backend.